# Ralink RT3290 Wireless Network hardware blocked

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, ralink

Here is my problem:
I have a double boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, which is an Asus R409L. When running on Win10, I do not have any wireless network issues. But when running on Ubuntu, the connection with the Ralink RT3290 network controller is sometimes fine, but generally fails.

These connection issues began approximately on 12/28/2019 and everything was fine for more than a year before. When down, wireless connection can sometimes randomly come back for a few minutes before dying again. There is no physical switch on the computer, only a keyboard shortcut that does not change situation when connection is down.

From the articles/forums I found on similar topics, I tried some commands to get more information on the issue (when connection is down):

```
    $ rfkill list
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes

###############################    
    $ iw dev | grep Interface
        Interface wlp3s0f0

###############################    
    $ sudo ifconfig wlp3s0f0 up
    SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill

###############################    
    $ iwconfig
    enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

    wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
              Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off

    lo        no wireless extensions.

###############################    
    $ ifconfig
    enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            ether <...>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 1303  bytes 1628255 (1.6 MB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 518  bytes 64881 (64.8 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
            device interrupt 18  

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 268  bytes 20683 (20.6 KB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 268  bytes 20683 (20.6 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

###############################    
    $ lspci -nn | grep -i net
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

Moreover, I found a message that seems to systematically appear when running `dmesg` just after the wireless connection dies (see attached image):[deauthenticating from...by local choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hR0O.png)

But I cannot figure out what to do whith this. I spent hours reading answers linked to RT3290 issues, but most of them seemed outdated.
Does someone have an idea for a possible solution ?
Or maybe a link to a forum that I missed ?

Found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) juste before posting, so that you can get all the wireless info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Jan 2020 17:55 CET +0100

Booted last: 09 Jan 2020 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib             118784  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2800pci,rt2800lib
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mac80211              819200  3 rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib,rt2800lib
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
cfg80211              679936  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
wmi                    28672  3 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  49152  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp3s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp3s0f0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       813     1  0 16:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0f0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.0.0-37-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0f0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0f0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Paris (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp3s0f0  14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0f0  Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     E7616298EEB7610CA2A53AF
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2800pci
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2800mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2800 MMIO library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     5E33FBFA772586ADF95C254
depends:        rt2x00mmio,rt2800lib,rt2x00lib
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2800mmio
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     9364B788841E900CA63C689
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2800lib
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rt2x00pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 pci library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     68B02F6EB81371BAD3D9D3B
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2x00pci
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rt2x00mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 mmio library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     DC4897609AC19F1B8E29958
depends:        rt2x00lib
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2x00mmio
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     F890B6F5A2497A4BBB19563
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2x00lib
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     0CDD28A506BDDDE9444E85C
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     DCECEA5B6FF7EF332DBC1F5
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800pci]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.371148] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 3290 detected
[    3.916170] rt2800pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0f0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.127698] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
[    5.127909] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[  304.523954] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down
[  452.270632] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
[  452.490323] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down
[  455.186291] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
[  917.040019] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down
[  933.098071] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  933.120444] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down
[  945.212377] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  945.236322] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down
[  957.301466] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  957.324484] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down
[  963.181504] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
[ 2335.845034] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[ 2335.848660] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
[ 3541.122659] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link Down

########## wireless info END ############
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll admit I do not know much about this issue.  I am trying to help you. Can you edit your question to show the actual Ubuntu version you are using.  At first read it appears you are using Ubuntu 10.04 which is End of Life in April 2013, that may be throwing off many people that see that and don't know anything about such an old OS.  You could also include two more tags for the OS version you are using [18.04] and [wireless].  These changes may get more people with answers to look at your question.  I hope you find help soon :)

Comment: Oops thank you... Indeed I mistyped. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem (actually with Debian 10.3) on my HP 350 G1/21B7 laptop having the same Ralink RT3290 network controller: the wifi connection fails after 5-15 minutes after reboot. The wifi icon disappears from the top panel of Gnome, and even reloading the rt2800pci driver does not help, only reboot. I did not noticed that connection can sometimes come back.

But **all this happens only with kernel versions 5.x, and not with 4.19.**
You may want to try with kernel 4.x.
I have not find yet any reference that it is an issue in kernel 5.x, though.

By the way, I also found lines like

```
wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ae:22:15:4a:de:da
wlo1: deauthenticating from ae:22:15:4a:de:da by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

e.g., in kern.log, but their timing do not seem to be related to connection fails.

Comment: Thanks, I might try it one day. I currently use my smartphone with USB internet connection sharing, that does the job for now ...